# Как напечатать Веб страницу в FastReport

Tags: c++, fastreport

Я программирую в c++ Builder 10.4, задача стоит в том что надо создать приложение, который в настройках указать адресс веб сайта, а он по этому веб сайту  напечатал, страницу сайта; Я сделал всю логику, но с печатью у меня пока нечего не получается, для отображение взял компонент CppWebBrowser. Хочу через FastReport организовать отчет который должен загружать из веб страницы, главную страницу, и отправить на печать, через FastReport я могу отправить на печать, а вот загрузить веб страницу на отчет FastReport не могу?, как мне это реализовать скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В данной истории, FastReport кажется совершенно лишней сущностью

Answer (score 0):

Сам FastReport подобного не умеет - у него нет "браузера". Как вариант - грузите страницу отдельно, программно делайте её "скриншот", передавайте полученную картинку в отчет и выводите её в нужном виде.

Comment: Можно что бы пользователь не заметил, как программа делает скриншот?

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Поищите, умеет ли ваш CppWebBrowser открываться и загружать страницы "незаметно" или поищите аналоги, которые так умеют.